# Webpack is not listed as a dependency of my app on my old machine. On my new machine, the app won't work without it

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, package.json

I recently had to exchange my work Mac. I'm working on a Next/React app. When I got my new machine I cloned the code, installed node and npm, and installed all the packages.

When I tried to start the application I got the following error:

```
WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'mode'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           mode: ...
         }
       })
     ]
```

The original package.json did not have webpack listed as a dependency. However, the package-lock.json included webpack as a dependency of some things.

When I ran npm install, I received the following warnings:

```
npm WARN terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@3.6.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN SVOCSupportTool@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I manually installed these dependencies. Now webpack and webpack-dev-middleware are listed as dependencies in my package.json.

I'm curious why I had to make these changes on my new machine, but my old machine seemingly didn't require webpack as dependency in package.json.

I tried deleting and re-installing the node-modules and the package-lock.json.

I confirmed the Node and Npm versions were the same as my old machine.

I figure these steps would resolve the dependency issues.